# c++ CLR to bridge a c++ dll with a c# application

Tags: c#, c++, log4net

I am trying to follow this example: `http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2008/06/19/Log4NET-for-C++.aspx`

to get `Log4Net` running in a c++ dll.

I created an empty CLR project, changed the output type to `lib`, and added the following code:

//Bridge.cpp

```
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace System;

/// <summary>

/// Example of how to simply configure and use log4net

/// </summary>
ref class LoggingExample
{
private:
    // Create a logger for use in this class
    static log4net::ILog^ log = log4net::LogManager::GetLogger("LoggingExample"); static LoggingExample()
    {
        log4net::Config::BasicConfigurator::Configure();
    }


public:static void ReportMessageWarning(char* msg)
{
    String^ data = gcnew String(msg);
    log->Warn(data);
}
       static void ReportMessageError(char* msg)
       {
           String^ data = gcnew String(msg);
           log->Error(data);
       }

       static void ReportMessageInfo(char* msg)
       {
           String^ data = gcnew String(msg);
           log->Info(data);
       }static void ReportMessageDebug(char* msg)
       {
           String^ data = gcnew String(msg);
           log->Debug(data);
       }
};

extern "C"
{

    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportMessageWarning(char* msg)
    {
        LoggingExample::ReportMessageWarning(msg);
    }
    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportMessageError(char* msg)
    {
        LoggingExample::ReportMessageError(msg);
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportMessageInfo(char* msg)
    {
        LoggingExample::ReportMessageInfo(msg);
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) void ReportMessageDebug(char* msg)
    {
        LoggingExample::ReportMessageDebug(msg);
    }
}
```

I have created a c++ console application project, and added this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>


extern "C"
{

    //log4net from the wrapper lib
    _declspec(dllimport) void ReportMessageWarning(char* msg);

    __declspec(dllexport) void RunTest() 
    {
        std::string message = "hey it seems it is working";
        ReportMessageWarning(_strdup(message.c_str()));
    }


}
```

This will be a c++ dll that is called from another C# application. 
I have compiled the clr lib, and linked it in the dependencies of the c++ application.

However, the c++ dll will not compile as is, giving me:

`Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ReportMessageWarning`

What have i missed here?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link the import library in your console project.

Comment: I added it in` Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies`, as I would in straight c++, is this correct?

Comment: Come to think of it, there is a special wrinkle when you let the C++/CLI compiler generate the unmanaged stub for a function.  In that specific case, the compiler only generates `_ReportMessageWarning` and not the `__imp_ReportMessageWarning` function pointer.  Remove `__declspec(dllimport)` from the declaration in your console project so the linker doesn't go looking for that pointer.